# How to use the given statement in firestore

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can i write this in Firebase firestore database

```
databse.getReference.child('chats').child(sender_uid).child("messages").set(message)
```

I'm using Firebase Firestore database for my project so i don't know how to write above statement in Firestore database.

Comment: This code is used for store data in realtime database firebase.

Comment: Yes i know but what is similar code to use for  storing   into  firestore database

Comment: There is no similar code in Firestore because the database is constructed from collections and documents. We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: Query is to create two rooms , sender and reciever's room both have message as a child field and then set that message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alex Mamo mentioned, you can't really query Firestore with that realtimeDB query but you can find this documentation instructions on how to get data from Firestore and build your queries, [get data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document):

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("rooms").document("messages");
// asynchronously retrieve the document
ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
// ...
// future.get() blocks on response
DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
if (document.exists()) {
  System.out.println("Document data: " + document.getData());
} else {
  System.out.println("No such document!");
```

The structure of the DB in Firestore in this example is as follows:

```
Rooms Collection
    Message document
       Content: String
       From: String
       To: String
```

Where each document represent a new message.

If you’d like to write data to a Firestore document, please refer to [Update a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data).